# Private methods or Inner class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a class which needs couple of helper methods. This methods are going to be used only by this class. So I am wondering which will be best practice i.e. whether declaring these helper methods as private methods or group them and put inside the inner class.

Comment: The criteria for creating an inner class are the same than for a regular class: there is a set of data and operations that you may naturally group together?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask yourself some questions:

- Are you certain that in the future these helper methods won't be used by other classes?
- Does the logic of those helper methods really functionally belong in that class? (high cohesion)

If both answers are yes, than go ahead and put them in that class. But you clearly doubt, so probably you should put them in another class.

Answer (score 0):

It only depends on the abstraction principle: if you are using "service" methods, for example a method to count a class' active instances, it will be better to declare them as private (and in this example, static):

```
private static count() {
    counter++; }
```

If you have an inner class, and these methods seems to be functions or actions performed by the objects represented by the inner class, you should declare them there. But since it doesn't seem to me that you already have an inner class in your main class (you are talking about group the methods in a new inner class), I would definitively declare the methods as private, if you are sure that the main class is the right place for these methods (think about abstraction principle) and other classes will not be using these methods (you can always change the accessibility later of course)